# Curl sandbox paypal php

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I call the Sandbox making a purchase. Once it made verify that the data comes from paypal with curl and these must reimburse the data but I returned SSL connect error.
They have changed TLSv1_2 but still putting  CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to TLSv1_2 not work for me.

```
    $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // Los separamos en un array
    $raw_post_array = explode('&',$raw_post_data);

    // Separamos cada uno en un array de variable y valor
    $myPost = array();
    foreach($raw_post_array as $keyval){
        $keyval = explode("=",$keyval);
        if(count($keyval) == 2)
            $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }

    // Nuestro string debe comenzar con cmd=_notify-validate
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
    if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')){
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
    }
    foreach($myPost as $key => $value){
        // Cada valor se trata con urlencode para poder pasarlo por GET
        if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
        } else {
            $value = urlencode($value);
        }

        //Añadimos cada variable y cada valor
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }
    $ch = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 'CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
    if( !($res = curl_exec($ch)) ) {
        // Ooops, error. Deberiamos guardarlo en algún log o base de datos para examinarlo después.
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        if($info!=false){
        $error="Problemas con la llamada a curl_exec ".curl_error($ch)." ".$info["ssl_verify_result"];
        $ddf = fopen('error.log','a');
        fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."] Error 4: $error\r\n");
        fclose($ddf);
        curl_close($ch);
        exit;
        }else{
            $error="Problemas con la llamada a curl_exec ".curl_error($ch);
            $ddf = fopen('error.log','a');
            fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."] Error 4: $error\r\n");
            fclose($ddf);
            curl_close($ch);
            exit;
        }
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

What am I doing wrong?Do I have to add something?Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_SSLVERSION expects an integer, not a string. See [function.curl-setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for details.
Basically you would set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
```

or, if your version of PHP does not define this [curl constant](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) (Available since PHP 5.5.19 and 5.6.3) , you can also use the integer value:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```